# Quotes in database escaped after malware cleansing

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, escaping

I have a Wordpress-based blog. There was a malware attack on the site, which totally locked a table and made the site inaccessible. After the hosting company cleaned it up, all the images (and other stuff, except for text) in my posts stopped displaying.

Upon investigation, I found that all the quotation marks `"` had been escaped, that is they had turned into `\"`. Here's a sample code from a Wordpress post:

```
<img title=\"Wendy&#39;s Chicken club - Fast food: ads vs reality\"
     height=\"344\" alt=\"Wendy&#39;s Chicken club\"
     src=\"http://www.sawantshah.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/image-thumb.png\"
     width=\"640\" border=\"0\" />
```

Now, how shall I turn these escaped quotes back to normal through SQL? Will a simple find and replace work for escape sequences?

Blog where the problem is occurring, for reference: [www.sawantshah.com](http://www.sawantshah.com).

Comment: Only the most recent post is without this problem because it was recently posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update my_table set my_column = replace(my_column, '\\"', '"');
```

Answer (score 4):

Before you actually do so, make sure your host has competently disabled the malware. Based on your post's question, they've replaced all `"` with `\"`, which might disable the malware until you revert `\"` back to `"` -- i.e. not necessarily what you want. Complain to your host and ask them "what gives?!?"/tell them they introduced a new problem before moving a step further.